Am I missing the point of 'keep build forever' in Jenkins?
I have a Jenkins job which I sometimes use to create releases, where the releases are stored as artifacts. When the release is created I mark the build as 'keep forever' so I can access the release artifact in the future.
However, these builds still disappear like all the others. Only 30 builds are kept at one time.
For example if I select the oldest build still available in the build history and click 'keep build forever' (so a lock appears next to it) and trigger a new build it disappears.
Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

There is an awkward little down arrow that may help you see more builds:

